# jQuery - iframe loops all DIVS in parent window?

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent

My site is using some iframes, when a specific link is clicked in one of the iframes I need to find all the other iframes in the parent page and refresh them.

In the past I've used the following, but that has been run in the parent.

```
$('div[id^="site-"]').each(function(i, obj) {
    location.reload();
})
```

Obviously this won't work when it's running in the iframe as the other iframes are in the parent. Is there anyway to find each div in the parent with an ID starting `site-` and refresh them ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the content of all the frames, including the parent page, hosted on the same domain? If not, then you will not be able to do what you require.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes all pages, parent and iframes and within the same domain/IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working using the following in the iframe:

```
frames = window.parent.document.querySelectorAll('[id^="site-"]');

$.each(frames, function(index, item) {
    console.log ( item )
});
```

Each entry in the console.log is the element I require.